# Ubuntu Server UFW NAT Issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, ufw

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A ufw-before-input -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

This input into my before.rules file stops me being able to ping the outside world. Before its fine i can ping google.co.uk after cant get out. Is there something wrong in my syntax here or what is the issue...? Im just trying to NAT my VPN so i can get internet access. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
William